# Largest US City Budgets

Tags: data-request

Is there a good source for comparable, machine readable data on the municipal/government budgets of the 30 largest (by population) US cities?

List of cities: (1. New York - 30. Las Vegas)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen that data compiled yet into a single dataset. The Open Knowledge Foundation has a list of cities which have their budget data online:

http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/budget